# adb can list devices but adb shell/logcat doesn't work

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb, vmware-player

#### Short version

`adb devices` can list device, but `adb shell` or `adb logcat` just hang and don't work.

#### Long version

Here are various command outputs.

```
/* system info */
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu-vm 3.8.0-19-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 18:16:28 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64    x86_64 GNU/Linux

/* udev info */
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 

$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II], GT-P7500 [Galaxy Tab 10.1]
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub



$ adb devices -l
List of devices attached 
0A3C294805017006       device usb:1-1 product:full_toroplus model:Full_AOSP_on_Toroplus device:toroplus

$ adb shell
/* no output, just hang */

$ adb logcat
/* no output either */

/* verbose mode */
$ ADB_TARCE=1 adb shell
system/core/adb/adb.c::main():Handling commandline()
system/core/adb/commandline.c::adb_commandline():starting interactive shell
system/core/adb/adb_client.c::_adb_connect():_adb_connect: host:version
..........
4f4b4159 OKAY
system/core/adb/adb_client.c::switch_socket_transport():Switch transport success
system/core/adb/transport.c::writex():writex: fd=3 len=4: 30303036 0006
system/core/adb/transport.c::writex():writex: fd=3 len=6: 7368656c6c3a shell:
system/core/adb/transport.c::readx():readx: fd=3 wanted=4
/* hang at this point */
```

It seems that adb server is expecting some data from phone but can not get it, thus it's stuck there.

I've tried:

- kill and restart adb server
- unplug and then plug phone
- reboot phone
- disable usb debug on phone and then enable it

Sometimes, after unplug/plug the phone, it will work for a while (I can do `adb shell`), but soon it stops working. And most of the time, unplug/plug phone even has no effect at all!

I'm running ubuntu as vmplayer guest. Host is windows 7.

Thanks in advance for any help or hints.

## UPDATE

After plug the phone into rear usb port, it suddenly works! But I'm not sure the problem is really solved. Will see.

Comment: "Full_AOSP_on_Toroplus" sounds like an aftermarket firmware build - could this be a problem with that phone firmware?  Are you able to talk to any other devices from this computer, or talk to this phone from other computers?

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Yes, it's a custom ROM. It works fine with my office PC running ubuntu natively. Just that it won't won't work running ubuntu inside vmplayer. So I guess it's somehow related to vmplay usb configurations.

Comment: I had the same problem. After plugging the phone into one of the rear usb ports, it also worked. This is to confirm that your solution works.

Comment: NAA but may be helpful: On windows, I had the same problem with cygwin but it works in the cmd

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same problem with adb shell hanging.   I am running an Ubuntu 12.04 VM guest on an Ubuntu host.   The problem for me was the USB Compatibility setting for the VM was set to 1.1, it needs to be at least 2.0.   To change the setting power down the VM and choose the "Edit virtual machine settings" in the VMPlayer startup menu.  Then select the "USB Controller" device and change "USB Compatibility" to USB 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, getting different results (none working good though) by trying different usb-ports on the computer. I finally decided to go to the store and buy a new USB-cable. Now it works flawlessly! I guess USB-cables can be worn or bad...

**Short story: Buy a new cable! Worked for me!**

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if that meant to be used that way, but I also have `adb shell` hanging, however running `echo my_command | adb shell` allowed me to run commands on the target.

E.g. `echo settings get secure sysui_qs_tiles | adb shell`

Also, `adb shell < /dev/stdin` might be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

For my VMWare combination (Windows 10 Host + Ubuntu 18 Guest + Galaxy S9) it actually worked after changing the USB compatibility to 1.1. No idea why, but worth a shot if you have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had tcp port forwarding setup with this command `adb forward tcp:4321 tcp:4321` and later I messed up the connection somehow.

Every time after that `adb shell` used to hang forever. Then I ran `ps aux | grep adb` and found this

```
❯ ps aux | grep adb
username          10319   2.4  0.0  4380992   3080   ??  Ss   12:41PM   5:40.20 adb -L tcp:5037 fork-server server --reply-fd 4
username          34406   0.0  0.0  4278688    776 s007  S+    3:51PM   0:00.01 grep --color=auto  --exclude-dir=.tox adb
```

So I killed the running process with `kill 10319` and voila... `adb shell` is back again.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.  I just removed the mouse usb cable connected to the second USB port and connected the phone cable to that(second USB port).  It worked!

Answer (score -1):

I've noticed if I plug in the usb into my mac first, **THEN** plug it into the android, adb works.
Perhaps this is why people notice different cables work? *(Happens to be connecting/disconnecting cables in a different order)*